# Assigning DataTable Values to Variables

Tags: vb.net, datatable

Let's say that I have a DataTable returned from SQL Server that has a column called ProductId which is an Int, and I want to assign the value of this field for a row to a local VB.Net variable ProductId. Can I just assign this value directly or do I need to convert it first? What is the best practice.

```
Dim dt As DataTable = GetMyDataTable()
Dim ProductId As Integer
For Each r As DataRow In dt.Rows
   ProductId = r("ProductId")
Next
```

Comment: `ProductId = r.Field(Of Int32)(ProdColumnIndex)`  Your code wont compile under `Option Strict` (a Best Practice) because `r("ProductId")` returns `Object`.  BTW, if you are fetching lots of product info from teh table, consider an ORM like Dapper